# Replacing empty values with a default value in a Linq to Entities query

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

In the Linq to Entities query below I need to place a default value in the x.Number in the returned value if the query returns 0 OfficeTelephone objects. I have tried 
x.Number??"555-1212" but that throws an error.

```
 from c in Contacts
                  .Where(a => a.LastName.Contains("ANDUS")).Take(10)
                       select new
                        {
                       Id = c.Id,
                       OfficeTelephone = c.Telephones.Where(a=>a.TelephoneType.Name.Contains("Office")).Select(x => new { x.AreaCode, x.Number, x.TelephoneType, x.Primary })
                        }
```

I've tried something like:

```
 from c in Contacts
                  .Where(a => a.LastName.Contains("ANDUS")).Take(10)
                       select new
                        {
                       Id = c.Id,
                       OfficeTelephone = c.Telephones
.Where(a=>a.TelephoneType.Name.Contains("Office"))
.Select(x => new { x.AreaCode, x.Number, x.TelephoneType, x.Primary })
.DefaultIfEmpty()}
```

But I'm not sure how to push a  default object into the DefaultIFEmpty()

Comment: If the query returns 0 objects, x.Number is never used...are you trying to set OfficeTelephone to a default value?

Comment: yes to a default object with default values for areacode, number,etc..

Answer (score 0):

Use `DefaultIfEmpty` and pass a default instance with those value which you would want by default i.e. if no rows are returned.

try it like this:

```
Contacts.Where(a=>a.LastName.Contains("ANDUS"))
        .Take(10)
        .Select(x => new 
        {
             Id = x.Id,
             OfficeTelephone = x.Telephones
                                .Where(a=> a.Telephone.Name.Contains("Office"))
                                .Select(b=> new Telephone
                                {
                                    b.AreaCode,
                                    b.Number,
                                    b.TelephoneType,
                                    b.Primary
                                })
                                .DefaultIfEmpty(new Telephone())
        });
```

where I've assumed that `typeof(x.Telephones) == typeof(List<Telephone>)`

Comment: That assumption is correct. When I do that I get the  error : Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<Telephone>

Comment: basically it says, you are trying to typecase an anonymous list into list of telephones, so just remove your anonymous list i.e. see my updated answer. try it out